# Filter JSON using bs4 or other and organize in excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I want to filter a json file from pool.pm

For example, https://pool.pm/wallet/$1111 and I want to get all the "policy"'s and how many time it repeats and organize it on a excel using openpyxl and in the first column the policies and in the 2nd column how many time it repeats

What I have:

```
import openpyxl
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


pooladd = str(input("Insira o address:\t"))

api_pool = "https://pool.pm/wallet/{}"
api_pool2 = api_pool.format(pooladd)
data = requests.get(api_pool2).json()
```

Output:

| Policy | How Many |
| --- | --- |
| f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a | 10 |
| 8728079879ce4304fd305b12878e0fcea3b8a3a5435a21b5dec35a11 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another implementation!, comments are added to the code.
Build the dictionary and then write the excel.

```
import openpyxl
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pooladd = str(input("Insira o address:\t"))

api_pool = "https://pool.pm/wallet/{}"
api_pool2 = api_pool.format(pooladd)
data = requests.get(api_pool2).json()

policies= [e_tkn['policy'] for e_tkn in data['tokens']]
unique_policies=set(policies)
result={}
for each_policy in unique_policies:
    result[each_policy]=policies.count(each_policy)

result=sorted(((value,key) for (key,value) in result.items()),reverse=True)# sort in decending order, reverse=True
print(result)
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 'Policy' # header
ws['B1'] = 'How Many' # header

row=2
for count,policy in result:
    ws['A' + str(row)]=policy # for each row, for example A2=policy
    ws['B' + str(row)]=count # for each row , for example B2 = count
    row=row+1
    
wb.save('policies.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag but in case you're interested, here is an approach with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

out = (
        pd.Series([t["policy"] for t in data["tokens"]])
            .value_counts()
            .to_frame("How Many")
            .reset_index(names="Policy")
      )
```

If you wanna make an Excel spreadsheet, use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) :

```
out.to_excel("output_file.xlsx", sheet_name="test_name", index=False)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
                                                     Policy  How Many
0  f0ff48bbb7bbe9d59a40f1ce90e9e9d0ff5002ec48f232b49ca0fb9a        10
1  8728079879ce4304fd305b12878e0fcea3b8a3a5435a21b5dec35a11         3
```